# How can I get this to fit the screen?

Tags: html, css

As the title says, I'd like the "background" element to fit the side of the screen (you can see it doesn't go all the way to the right), as well as to go all the way to the bottom of the screen. Can anyone help?

The code can be seen here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/ranchman/pen/MEWmvr)

(specifically these elements)

```

```
.background {
  background: url("https://static.kent.ac.uk/nexus/ems/50.jpg");
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.text {
  margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  height: auto;
}
.text p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```

Comment: By me it does go till the end what browser/version are you running?

Comment: Tested in both chrome and firefox, latest versions.

Comment: Look at this codepen is this what you had in mind https://codepen.io/DavidGenger/pen/mBdmjV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting margin and padding to 0, then setting background width to 100% seemed to do the trick. Is this the desired result?

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.background {
  background: url("https://static.kent.ac.uk/nexus/ems/50.jpg");
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.text {
  margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  height: auto;
}
.text p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes! That fixed the side issue, now can I somehow get these elements to go all the way to the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Setting `margin: -20px;` on the `<header>` pulls it out of the page, and with that creating the horizontal scroll bar, by removing the `margin: -20px;` the header will be placed fully in the document and the scrollbar will disappear.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/DavidGenger/pen/mBdmjV)

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you gave `border: 3px solid black;` in your background class that's why it is not showing correctly.

If you want to use border at top and bottom then you can do like this

```
.background {
  background: url("https://static.kent.ac.uk/nexus/ems/50.jpg");
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

So the conclusion is you have to remove the border from left and right after then you can get the result you want.

Here you can see difference [Codepan](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMRmXZ)

Hope this will helps you